# Tricks to find out if site is written in MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

Anyone know if any easy way to find out if a site is written in mvc?

And to take it a step further, assuming it is mvc to determine which pieces are asp.net forms?

I know just because they do or dont exist it doesn't mean 100% but it would be nice to have some things to look for certain headers that exist, or even existence of boilerplate code

i.e.(just a forms example):

```
onsubmit="javascript:return WebForm_OnSubmit();
```

Comment: Why are you trying to find that out?

Comment: I like a site, and I am trying to find out if it is mvc or asp.net forms.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, you can't, at least no way that would be reliable, short of emailing the site's developer.

Comment: +1 but I know there is no 100% reliable way, but I am looking for things that generally mean the site is MVC.

Comment: There's nothing you can do.  Routing has been updated to allow it to work with web forms.  Headers are not reliable at all. You're just SOL.

Answer (score 2):

Unless the site developer has removed it, you get a header on each response that indicates the ASP.NET MVC version.  I've tried this on three different sites I have using all three versions of MVC and it always appears.

```
X-Aspnetmvc-Version:1.0
X-Aspnetmvc-Version:2.0
X-Aspnetmvc-Version:3.0
```

*note: StackOverflow removes all of the ASP.NET injected headers as far as I can tell*

Comment: This header is not there when I inspect a request to StackOverflow.com in chrome... Either because Chrome doesn't see it, or because SO has actively disabled the default (but why?). But I know for a fact that SO is built on ASP.NET MVC.

Comment: @Tomas - I believe they remove all the ASP headers - they do add some overhead and give some indications of attack vectors.  I've checked it on several of my sites and it always shows up.  I suppose it could also be removed by caching servers, load balancers, etc., though one of my sites is behind a load balancer and it still has the header.

Comment: I believe that text comes from machine.config. Some folks advise removing it for security purposes. That means that its absence doesn't prove anything about MVC.

Comment: @tvanofsson: OK, well, that explains it. I just didn't see a reason to do so, but both overhead and security are valid reasons for a site like SO.

Comment: @DOK: I never said the absence of MVC-specific headers proves anything - quite the opposite; I said that SO *is* built on MVC, but *doesn't* have them, ergo the headers aren't an accurate method if you need absolutely certainty.

Comment: @Tomas Lycken, I was not addressing your comment.

Answer (score 2):

Well, the most obvious clue is that you don't have extensions to urls (like .aspx). Right?

Comment: But how you tell the difference between a site written in Ruby/Rails and ASP.NET MVC?

Comment: The ASP.NET WebForms can be used in the ASP.NET MVC application – the *.aspx files just should be ignored by the routing engine (specified within the Global.asax file).

Comment: You can use the System.Web.Routing to make extensionless Urls map to .aspx pages behind the scenes.

Comment: +1 @tvanfosson right on.

Answer (score 1):

The `<input type="hidden" name="__VIEWSTATE" id="__VIEWSTATE" value="" />` tag does not exist :)

Comment: This just means it was *not* built on ASP.NET WebForms - it could just as well be php or something else...

Answer (score 1):

Fire up [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) during the use of a website like www.codeplex.com and you can view header information:[image]

Comment: All I see are asp.net session ids, so I guess i will look to interrogate the code further.

Comment: Conversely, look for PHPSESSID and you'll know it's not .NET let alone .NET MVC.

Answer (score 0):

The X-AspNetMvc-Version header can be disabled in your Global.asax.cs file:

```
protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MvcHandler.DisableMvcResponseHeader = true;
    // ...
}
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.